What is this thread on a gardening spraying head?
Several years ago I bought a cheap spraying head off Amazon which had a plastic quick connect fitting to attach it to gardening hoses.
This plastic piece has since become too worn and started leaking through its scratches. So I want to replace the fitting, measured its thread diameter and got a brass G3/4 fitting. It turns out that the threads have a differing slope, so they don't quite fit.
Both pieces have an outer diameter of a little over 26 mm (compatible with G3/4). The brass piece has the regular 1.8 mm slope (14 threads per inch), whereas the original piece (black plastic) has a larger slope of around 2.3 mm (possibly 11 threads per inch)
The image shows both pieces. What is the thread on the original black plastic piece? I couldn't determine any fitting thread norm based on my searches.


Garden hoses use GHT size threads.  Unknown if G threads are the same, but does not seem so by your picture.

@crip659 Yep seems to be an American style 3/4" - 11.5 TPI thread. Rather unusual here in Euroland i guess :)
